# NodeMCU Arduino set PWM Frequency to specific frequency

Tags: arduino-ide, pwm, timers, nodemcu

I am using NodeMCU and I program it using Arduino IDE, I need to change the PWM frequency of a port, in Arduino I used to change the frequency using timers registers like that:

```
TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0xF8) | 1 ;
```

How can I change the frequency of a digital pin using some function like that:

```
analogWriteFrequency(pin, 31250);
```

So that the code will looks like that:

```
#ifdef __AVR__
TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0xF8) | 1 ; //generates the MCKL signal
#else
analogWriteFrequency(pin, 31250);
#endif
analogWrite(pin, 128) ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> PWM frequency is 1kHz by default. Call `analogWriteFreq(new_frequency)` to change the frequency.

[source](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md)

Comment: Thanks.
but, can I adjust it to a specific pin ?

Comment: Probably not. They probably all use the same single PWM generator.

Comment: Source link is 404.